# Window.print() sets default copies to 2

Tags: javascript, printing, printing-web-page

I have a requirement that by clicking on a button, the printer dialog will open with the number of copies set to 2 instead of the default number 1.

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: Is this still not possible in 2019?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible using pure javascript with window.print().

However, if you are open to using Java Applet, take a look at [qz-print aka jzebra](https://github.com/qzindustries/qz-print). I have personally used this in some past projects for some advance printing requirements and the result is very satisfying. Take a look at their printHTML() method

```
***************************************************************************
    * Prototype function for printing plain HTML 1.0 to a PostScript capable 
    * printer.  Not to be used in combination with raw printers.
    * Usage:
    *    qz.appendHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
    *    qz.printPS();
    ***************************************************************************/ 
    function printHTML() {
        if (notReady()) { return; }

        // Preserve formatting for white spaces, etc.
        var colA = fixHTML('<h2>*  QZ Print Plugin HTML Printing  *</h2>');
        colA = colA + '<color=red>Version:</color> ' + qz.getVersion() + '<br />';
        colA = colA + '<color=red>Visit:</color> http://code.google.com/p/jzebra';

        // HTML image
        var colB = '<img src="' + getPath() + 'img/image_sample.png">';

                //qz.setCopies(3);
        qz.setCopies(parseInt(document.getElementById("copies").value));

        // Append our image (only one image can be appended per print)
        qz.appendHTML('<html><table face="monospace" border="1px"><tr height="6cm">' + 
        '<td valign="top">' + colA + '</td>' + 
        '<td valign="top">' + colB + '</td>' + 
        '</tr></table></html>');

        qz.printHTML();
    }
```

Of course if you just want to print 2 copies, this may be way too over killed and too complicated to implement. But I'm not aware of any other way that can help you interfere with the browser's printing.